# Выборка в MySQL с дублирующем ключом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных MySQL.

В таблице есть два столбца, `product_id (int)` и `avail (int)`.

`product_id` может повторять N раз, а `avail` только 0 и 1 значения.

Нужно выбрать из таблицы `product_id` где все `avail = 0`

Пример

```
product_id | avail
-----------+------
138        | 0
138        | 1
140        | 0
140        | 0
```

Comment: А покажите `show create table` для таблицы? И индексы можно произвольно добавлять/менять? Какие еще действия или выборки с таблицей возможны? Это поможет указать более точный запрос

Answer (score 1):

Я умею только так, возможно не лучший вариант.

Раз только 0 и 1 и надо выбрать все нули, это тоже самое, что их сумма равно 0.

```
select product_id, avail 
  from (select product_id, avail, sum(avail) as sum 
    from t1 
    group by product_id) as tmp 
  where sum = 0
```

Comment: 1) Если `sum(avail) as sum` равно 0, значит `avail` выбирать из БД и не надо, оно и так равно 0; 2) если `sum = 0` за пределами вложенного запроса, значит временная таблица, которая хранит этот запрос, так же содержит и записи с `sum > 0` и они будут передаваться во внешний запрос для сравнения, а оно нам надо? Если перенести условие во вложенный запрос (т.е. сделать `having sum = 0`), то лишние записи передаваться не будут, что скажется на скорости. Но в данном случае внутренний запрос будет содержать все необходимые данные, т.е. внешний запрос можно убрать и ответ примет вид ответа @Deonis

Comment: @BOPOH я с вами полностью согласен. к сожалению, так и не удосужился прочитать что-нить про mysql. живу на эмпирических знаниях :) ответ появился, потому что  из "лучше ничего, чем  плохо" или "лучше плохо, чем ничего" я выбрал второе :) по хорошему, после ответа Deonis можно бы мой и убить, но, наверное, ваш комментарий будет полезен таким, как я  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `tbl` GROUP BY `product_id` HAVING SUM(`avail`) = 0
```

Comment: Если будем работать с индексом, то `max(avail)` должен отрабатывать быстрее, т.к. не надо будет просматривать все строки